# How to stop native phone call activity from displaying?

Tags: android

## Background

Our team is developing an app that needs to be able to make calls from a personalized list of contacts. The app also should be able to handle the call from within it's activity, and not the native one.

Using the ITelephony interface it is already capable of turning speaker and mute on/off, also ending the call. The problem is that the call() method from ITelephony (the one that makes calls) requires a permission that is protected, only system level apps can access it.

At this moment we are using a workaround, we make the call using Intent.ACTION_CALL, and once the call is stared we place our calling activity on top of the native using a broadcast receiver that listens to NEW_OUTGOING_CALL. It works, but when we make the call the native activity pops on the screen and only then our activity is started, which looks awful.

Receiver:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "OutgoingCallReceiver CHAMADO");
    //abortBroadcast();

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(context, CallingViewImpl.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //waiting 1 second so the native activity won't pop up on top of our activity
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    context.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

[Here's a gif showing the flow, don't mind the alert error, it is because I was using a phone with no sim card.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKP8j.gif)

## Question

Is there anyway to prevent the native activity from appearing without stopping the call? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: any solution? how shall a communication app handle this?

Comment: Unfortunately there was nothing I could without root to solve the problem. I just draw my activity over the native one and don't let the user close it before the native one is closed too.